NullPointerException when using Openllet in Java
When I create an ontology manager in Java code using owlapi and Openllet libraries, NullPointerException occurs.
Adding opellet 2.6.5 to project throws the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.<init>(Optional.java:107)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.of(Optional.java:120)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(FindOps.java:194)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(FindOps.java:191)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findAny(ReferencePipeline.java:548)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.utilities.Injector.getImplementation(Injector.java:246)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:119)
at com.owltest.App.main(App.java:27)

Without Openllet manager is created. But I need Openllet for swrl rules with built-ins.

Exceptions in the Injector class means the library cannot find implementations for some interfaces, which implies an incomplete classpath or a clash of different OWLAPI versions. Can you add details of your classpath? E.g., if you use maven, your pom.xml. Otherwise the full list of jars in your classpath.

github with my pom.xml

Exception was called because I didn't add in pom.xml openllet-core
